# Error : Main method not found in java class

Tags: java, javac, factorial

I am new to concepts of java. while preparing my first program of classes with objects i encountered a problem. here is the code and the error..please resolve..
PROGRAM:

```
class Fact
{
    private int i;
    private int n;
    private int fact;

    public Fact()
        { fact=1;
          i=1;
        }
    public Fact( int x)
        { n=x; }
    public void getAnswer()
        {
            while(i<=n)
            {fact=fact*i;
                i++;}
            System.out.println(fact);
        }
}
class FactMain
{
    public static void main(String dt[])
    {
    Fact obj= new Fact(6);
    obj.getAnswer();
    }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Main method not found in class Fact, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Can you show or descript what your are doing and when you get the error.

Comment: Ahh, shouldn't you be trying to run `FactMain`, assuming that `FactMain` resides within the `FactMain.class`. How are you executing the program?  Does the `FactMain` class reside within `FactMain.java` separate from `Fact` class?

Comment: if you would like to run the program the class `FactMain` must be `public` and you have to run this class

Comment: yes..on typing java FactMain it shows result as 0

Comment: @SitanshuKhosla So `Fact` and `FactMain` are in separate java files?  Cause your post is really, really confusing...

Comment: first i have declared a class Fact and declared code to calculate factorial of any number. then i declared another class FactMain that holds the object of the first class. on compiling i get two separate classes Fact.class and FactMain.class

Comment: @SitanshuKhosla General advice, place the class `Fact` in `Fact.java` and the `FactMain` class in `FactMain.java`, generally, a .java should contain only one class declaration (excluding inner classes, but that's another topic), otherwise you could run into some interesting issues

Comment: after placing them in separate file i should be running java FactMain or java Fact??

Comment: @SitanshuKhosla Run the class with the `main` method (`FactMain`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the class file name `Fact.java` to `FactMain.java`.

```
private int fact;

public Fact()
    { fact=1;
      i=1;
    }
public Fact( int x)
    { n=x; }
```

Note, your default constructor set `fact` but constructor `Fact( int x)` set `n`. Hence `fact` is `0`. So your output is `0` too.

**Solution:**

```
public Fact(int x) {
    fact = 1;
    i = 1;
    n = x;
}
```

Or,

```
public Fact(int x) {
    this(); // default constructor
    n = x;
}
```

**Here is the complete solution:**

Create a single `class` file named `FactMain.java`, then paste the following code:

```
class Fact {
    private int i;
    private int n;
    private int fact;

    public Fact() {
        fact = 1;
        i = 1;
    }

    public Fact(int x) {
        this();
        n = x;
    }

    public void getAnswer() {
        while (i <= n) {
            fact = fact * i;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(fact);
    }
}

class FactMain {
    public static void main(String[] dt) {
        Fact obj = new Fact(6);
        obj.getAnswer();
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows result as 0. other than renaming i can simply run java FactMain

Comment: tried..didnt work..i did not separate them. saved file as FileMain.java.. javac FileMain.java .. java FileMain.. output 0

Answer (score 1):

just change your Parameterized constructor to this

```
public Fact(int x) {
    fact = 1;
    i = 1;
    n = x;
}
```

because you declare **factorial** in **default constructor** and you are not calling it. So, **0** is assigned to factorial and then you r trying to multiply it. Which makes no sense.

Comment: does not work.. though your concept is correct.. correct method                  public Fact(int x) { i=1; fact=1; n=x;}  works fine

Answer (score 0):

You have saved your file as `Fact.java`. So java is trying to find the main class in Fact. Save your file as `FactMain.java` It should work.

Comment: Given the fact it's not possible to know where `Fact` and `FactMain` actually reside it's a mess which needs clarification. I can't see how renaming the `Fact.java` file, which contains the public `Fact` class to `FactMain.java` would resolve the issue anyway (but I'm feeling rather confused so far)

Answer (score 0):

Your main method is in ***FactMain.java***, but you are saving a file as ***Fact.java***.

You will need to save the file as ***FactMain.java*** as JVM expects main to be in the same class as the name of .java file.

Comment: `FactMain`, not `FaceMain`. And simply renaming `Fact` to `FactMain` isn't a real solution, as it "seems" to also contain `public Fact`, so the better solution would be to separate the two into there own java files...IMHO

Comment: other than renaming i can simply run FactMain since it holds the object of the class Fact

Comment: If you have declared FactMain class in other file FactMain.java and you have Fact.java file in same class that will work fine. Otherwise you will need to rename the file as FactMain.java. 

JVM looks for the public static main method in the same class as that of main method.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your main class in FactMain and most probably after compilation while running you're trying to execute

> java Fact

And hence you got the error because there is no main method in Fact class.
Once you compile the .java file you will get two class files Fact.class and FactMain.class so you should execute

> java FactMain

Answer (score 0):

Move the `FactMain` class to `FactMain.java`

## FactMain.java

```
public class FactMain
{
    public static void main(String dt[])
    {
        Fact obj= new Fact(6);
        obj.getAnswer();
    }
}
```

Allow the `Fact` class to remain in the `Fact.java` file

## Fact.java

```
public class Fact {

    private int i;
    private int n;
    private int fact;

    public Fact() {
        fact = 1;
        i = 1;
    }

    public Fact(int x) {
        this();
        n = x;
    }

    public void getAnswer() {
        while (i <= n) {
            fact = fact * i;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(fact);
    }
}
```

Compile the classes...

```
javac {package path}\FactMain.java
```

Run the main class

```
java {package path}.FactMain
```

Comment: tried..separated the code.. in one file Fact that contains members.. in other file FileMain that contains object.. saved them as File.java and FileMain.java.. on cmd javac File.java then Javac FileMain.java..then java FileMain.. output 0

Comment: the default constructor was conflicting.. solution by @rakeb,void worked

Comment: how come i == 0.. if System.out.println is showing 0 then its because the fact variable is getting value of 0 after loop ends

Comment: @SitanshuKhosla `fact * i`, where `fact` is `0`, means you're doing `0 * i` which is `0`, so when you call `this()` from `Fact(int)`, you initalise `fact` to `1`, which would result in value of `720`, but now we're leaving the topic of the original question

Comment: yes..i got the answer...but separating the two classes as you said did not work.. so is it only the problem of constructor??

Comment: @SitanshuKhosla The problem of *"Main method not found in class Fact"* had to do with you class been defined in a single class, which could be resolved, more cleanly, be separating them.  The "bug" in your code was because you weren't chaining the constructors together, so `fact` was been initialized to `0`